# Request returns Invalid or nonexistent Content-Type even if I put content-type in header

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, request-promise

I'm trying to create an app-managed bucket but am encountering the error: `Invalid or nonexistent Content-Type, accepted values are {text/json, application/json}`

I'm using node.js and request-promise package. The error is confusing to me because I am setting my `content-type` within the headers of the request to `application/json`.

Here's my function which makes the request:

```
let globalOptions = {
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
};
function createAppManagedBucket(){
    let forgeToken = "eyJhb..."
    const options = Object.assign({}, globalOptions, {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets`,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise' 
        },
        form: {
            "bucketKey": `someTestBucket`,
            "policyKey": `transient`
        },
        auth: {
            'bearer': forgeToken
        },
        json: true
    })
    return rp(options)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.body
    }).catch((err) => {
        return err
    })
}
```

It seems like even though I've set `Content-Type: application/json` within the header my request is being forced to have `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If I log the response of this, then I get the error and it looks like my request is actually correct since these are my headers:

```
rawHeaders:
[ 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
'Authorization, Accept-Encoding, Range, Content-Type',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
'GET',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
'*',
'Content-Type',
'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'Date',
'Tue, 09 Apr 2019 15:58:07 GMT',
'Strict-Transport-Security',
'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
'Content-Length',
'99',
'Connection',
'Close' ],
```

But further down in the request I see

`_header: 'POST /oss/v2/buckets HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nUser
e\r\nhost: developer.api.autodesk.com\r\nauthorization: Bearer eyJhb...\r\naccept: application/json\r\ncontent-length: 43\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'`

Where I can see that the `content-type` is actually changing to `application/form_urlencoded`So it looks like my `content-type` is being forced to something other than what I set in the header. Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Comment: what are `globalOptions`?

Comment: sorry something i forgot to remove, but i'll put them in now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `request` options [documentation](https://github.com/request/request/#requestoptions-callback),

> `form` - when passed an object or a querystring, this sets `body` to a querystring representation of value, and adds `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded header`. When passed no options, a FormData instance is returned (and is piped to request). See "Forms" section above.

You can't mix the `json` and `form` request options like you are doing without the Content Type being ambiguous